# What colors names mentioned in Quran?

Tags: quran

I want to know that how many total colors that are mentioned in Holy Quran and what are the names of that colors.

Comment: There are six colors mentioned in the qur'an.

Comment: can you please tell me the names of that colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the word (the) color (Arabic اللون) itself has been mentioned in the qur'an nine times.

Further only six colors have been mentioned clearly by their names, but more can be found when checking details.

The first color (if we start reading the qur'an starting with al-Fatihah and ending with an-Nas) which was mentioned is:

- (The) **yellow** (Arabic الأصفر) which was mentioned in (2:96)

  Further the qur'an has mentioned: (Verses and links will be added later)
- (The) **green** (Arabic الأخضر) like in (18:13)
- (The) **red** (Arabic الأحمر) like in (35:27)
- (The) **blue** (Arabic الأزرق) like in (20:102)
- (The) **white** (Arabic  الأبيض) like in (3:107)
- (The) **black** (Arabic الأسود)  like in (3:106)

Furthermore the qur'an referred to specific colors (or nuances of them) without clearly quoting the exact names.

- The **pink** (Arabic الوردي) can be concluded from:

  > وردة كالدهان.
  >   rose-colored like oil. 
  >   ([55:37](https://legacy.quran.com/55/37))

  Note that this verse is often counted as referring to red too.
- The **dark green** (Arabic الأخضر الغامق) can be concluded from:

  > مدهامتان. 
  >   Dark green [in color].
  >   ([55:64](https://legacy.quran.com/55/64))

  Note that this verse is tricky as

  > مدهمة or مدهم

  In Arabic refers to black.
  While

  > مدهامة

  To a green that is close to black.
- The (reddish) **black** (Arabic الأسود الذي فيه حمرة or الأسود الذي خالطته حمرة) means a black that might be mixed with few reddish spots or surfaces. Some of the tafsir call it also rust-colored. 
  This can be concluded from:

  > أحوى.
  >   black stubble. 
  >   ([87:5](https://legacy.quran.com/87/5))

And there are even more of these kinds of examples.

Answer (score 4):

There are 8 colors mentioned in the Quran.

- **Red** occurs in the Quran only once ([35:27](https://quran.com/35/27))
- **Yellow**, occurs total five times in the Quran ([2:69](https://quran.com/2/69), [30:51](https://quran.com/30/51), [39:21](https://quran.com/39/21), [57:20](https://quran.com/57/20), [77:33](https://quran.com/77/33)).
- **Blue** is used once in the Quran, in an allegory about the hereafter. [20:102](https://quran.com/20/103)
- **Green** appears throughout the Quran as a color that symbolises life ([6:99](https://quran.com/6/99), [12:43](https://quran.com/12/43), [12:46](https://quran.com/12/46), [18:31](https://quran.com/18/31), [22:63](https://quran.com/22/63), [36:80](https://quran.com/36/80), [55:76](https://quran.com/55/76), [76:21](https://quran.com/76/21)).
- **Pink** appears in the Quran to denote the alarming colour of a disintegrated sky ([55:37](https://quran.com/55/37)).
- **Dark Green** occurs in the Quran only once ([55:64](https://quran.com/55/64)). As the colour of dense foliage, it allegorically portrays the thriving life of eternal garden.
- **White** appears in the Quran mainly to describe states of minds reflecting light of spiritual awareness ([2:187](https://quran.com/2/187), [7:108](https://quran.com/7/108), [20:22](https://quran.com/20/22), [26:33](https://quran.com/26/33), [27:12](https://quran.com/27/12), [28:32](https://quran.com/28/32), [35:27](https://quran.com/35/27), [37:46](https://quran.com/37/46), [37:49](https://quran.com/37/49); [3:106](https://quran.com/3/106), [3:107](https://quran.com/3/107), [12:84](https://quran.com/12/84)).
- **Black**, occurs to describe states of minds lacking light of spiritual awareness ([2:187](https://quran.com/2/187), [16:58](https://quran.com/16/58), [35:27](https://quran.com/35/27), [39:60](https://quran.com/39/60), [43:17](https://quran.com/43/17), [3:106](https://quran.com/3/106)).

Islam, Siraj. 2017. “Various Colours in the Quran.” Lamp of Islam. Retrieved (https://lampofislam.wordpress.com/2017/03/25/various-colours-in-the-quran/).

Comment: Thank you so much