# Translation of this particular verse?

Tags: quran, quran-translation, arabic-translation

Selamun aleikum,

Can someone give me a literal translation of these particular verses (and add a little bit of explaining):

Surah Al-Ala, Verses 4/5:

> وَالَّذِي أَخْرَجَ الْمَرْعَىٰ

> فَجَعَلَهُ غُثَاءً أَحْوَىٰ

I already know what is meant, but the translations are translating أَحْوَىٰ as black, how is pasture getting black? The word غُثَاءً also varies with up to many words in the translations.
The translations varies in wording, I personally favor the literal ones, but I don’t know, which one is more literal.

One of the English translations (Saheeh International):

> (4)And who brings out the pasture
> (5)And [then] makes it black stubble.

I only need a quick Arabic lesson here.

Comment: One of them is addressed [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/58428/what-colors-names-mentioned-in-quran)

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I won’t say it’s right, but the possibility of mud (after rain) on the wide pasture is maybe this reddish black. So the pasture turns to a reddish black scum (after rain), because the other word is translated in the internet as scum. Maybe it would fit, but I‘m not sure. Because from the literal words I have now I get: „And who brings out the pasture and then makes it reddish black scum (after rain?).“ I‘m just giving a thought.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/oxBY86fQq91xqPSC9

Answer (score -1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stubble_burning

The stubble turns black afterwards because it is burned in order for the farmland to be reused.